# 'int' is not callable on my Object with a custom Function

Tags: class, object, integer, init, callable

I'm learning Objects & Classes and am doing some practice. I've essentially done the exact same thing before but now with different names for my Classes and Objects. Here's my code (the error occurs on the second to last line):

[My code inside of Sublime editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVqVQ.png)

I've gone over this a few times and compared it to the lesson I followed and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198). Also, please include the full text of the error message in your question.